# I built an arduino conductivity sensor and it is showing low voltage in salty solutions and high voltage in tap water, is this an issue in code

Tags: c++, arduino

I built an arduino conductivity sensor to read the voltage in different solutions. It is showing me around 1.37 volts in tap water, and 0.35 volts in a solution with 10 ml of dissolved salt. Shouldn't it be the opposite? Am I reading this wrong or is this an issue in code.
Here is my code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// LCD pins <--> Arduino pins
const int RS = 11, EN = 12, D4 = 5, D5 = 4, D6 = 3, D7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(RS, EN, D4, D5, D6, D7);

const int switchPin = 6;
int switchState = 0;
int condVal;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    lcd.begin(16,2);
    pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  condVal = analogRead(A0);
  float voltage = condVal*(5.0/1023.0);
  

  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Cond: ");
  lcd.print(voltage);
  lcd.print(" V");

  delay(100);
}
```

I apologize if there is an obvious answer to this, I have never worked with electricity in this capacity before

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with this kinda sensor, but make some sense the voltage drop in saltier solution, because high conductive solutions make the current rise and the voltage drop.